# В чем отличие написания в скобках от написания без скобок

Tags: xcode, objective-c, warning, code-style

Пробую писать на Objective C и столкнулся с такой штукой:

```
self.updateInterface;
```

Выдаёт Warning, а

```
[self updateInterface];
```

Нет.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А вы ворнинги читаете?
И интересно, что вы хотели получить, написав просто 
     self.updateInterface;

Comment: Читал, сейчас не помню что было написано. Написав просто `self.updateInterface;` я хотел вызвать метод «*updateInterface*».

Comment: Методы так не вызываются. `self.updateInterface;` - так можно обратиться к свойству. А методы всегда вызываются через квадратные скобки, точнее так объекту посылается сообщение. 
Синтаксис у Obj-C слегка специфический, поэтому лучше теорию почитать. Например, вот тут неплохо написано - http://habrahabr.ru/post/107126/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень хорошо обсуждается здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/style-dot-notation-vs-message-notation-in-objective-c-2-0?rq=1

Вот краткий пересказ принятого там ответа в свободной форме:

```
Do not use dot for behavior. Use dot to access or set attribute like stuff, typically attributes declared as properties.
```

То есть точку можно и, как многие считают, желательно, использовать для свойств, объявленных с помощью @property и нельзя (нежелательно, хотя и не невозможно ;)) использовать для поведения, то есть для селекторов.

Так, например, в случае с updateInterface (это селектор, то есть поведение) нужно писать через [self updateInterface], а вот для, скажем, view.subviews лучше использовать `for (NSView *v in myView.subviews) { ... };`, а не `for (NSView *v in [myView subviews]) { ... };`

Там же смотрите хороший ответ про "за" и "против" использования точки: Dot notation pros and cons, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370847/598057